# Why do Jest give ReferenceError's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

## Question

Can anyone figure out, why I get this error?:

```
● Test suite failed to run

  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockResponseData' before initialization

  > 1 | const axios = require('axios');
      |               ^
```

Here is a online version. https://repl.it/@SandraSchlichti/jest-playground-2#getStatusCode.test.js

**getStatusCode.test.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getStatusCode = require('./getStatusCode');

const mockResponseData = {
  status: 301,
  statusText: 'Moved Permanently',
  headers: {
    location: 'https://www.google.com/',
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    date: 'Thu, 12 Nov 2020 10:09:41 GMT',
    expires: 'Sat, 12 Dec 2020 10:09:41 GMT',
    'cache-control': 'public, max-age=2592000',
    server: 'gws',
    'content-length': '220',
    'x-xss-protection': '0',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
    connection: 'close'
  }
};

// whenever Axios is called from getStatusCode() it won't make a network
// connection, but return the following instead
jest.mock("axios", () => {
  return {
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      data: mockResponseData
    })
  };
});

describe("test getStatusCode ", () => {
  // pretend to get data from the network connection
  let response;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    response = await getStatusCode({
      url: 'https://google.com',
      statusCode: 200,
      timeout: 1000,
      maxRedirects: 0
    });
  });

  // compare returned data with expected
  it("fetches raw response but we are only interested in the statuscode", async () => {
    // ensure the mocked Axios function has been called
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  describe('return value', () => {
    it('should be greater than or equal to zero', () => {
      expect(response).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0)
    })

      describe('have mocked axios.get() returned data.status', () => {
        it('should have returned 301', async () => {
          expect(await axios.get.mock.results[0].value).toHaveProperty('data.status', 301)
        })
      })
    })

    describe('axios returning rejected promise', () => {
      beforeAll(() => {
        // returning transformed mock
        axios.get.mockRejectedValue({
          data: mockResponseData
        });
      });

    describe('called with arguments', () => {
      let response;
      beforeAll(async () => {
        response = await getStatusCode({
          url: 'https://google.com',
          statusCode: 200,
          timeout: 1000,
          maxRedirects: 0
        });
      });

      it('should return -1', async () => {
        expect(await response.toEqual(-1));
      });
    });
  });

});
```

**getStatusCode.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

module.exports = async (options) => {
  options              = options || {};
  options.url          = options.url || {};
  options.statusCode   = options.statusCode || 0;
  options.timeout      = options.timeout || 1000;
  options.maxRedirects = options.maxRedirects || 0;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(options.url, {
      timeout: options.timeout,
      maxRedirects: options.maxRedirects,
      // make all http status codes a success
      validateStatus: function (status) {
        return true;
      }
  });

    console.log(response);


    return (response.status === options.statusCode) ? 1 : 0;
  } catch (error) {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest hoists all of the calls to `jest.mock` on the top of the scope ([it's mentioned in few places in the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports)). And even though it's also mentioned that the variables prefixed with `mock` will also be hoisted apparently they go below the jest.mock calls causing this error to happen.

I can advice you to use the auto-mocking feature of jest

```
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios')

// and then you'll be able to mock it's return value
axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
  data: mockResponseData
})
```

it will include the module and will generate a mock function for each of it's methods. And it's biggest benefit is whenever a library method is removed jest won't generate a mock function for it and your test will fail.

[repl.it example](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/jest-playground-2#getStatusCode.test.js)

Comment: Can I ask a bonus question? =) Given that I at line 36 have `statusCode: 200` so my `getStatusCode()` should return 0, which it does. `getStatusCode()` can however also return `1` if ``statusCode: 301`. How can I add this scenario?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Sure, always enjoy good questions :) You can do something like [this](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/jest-playground-3#getStatusCode.test.js)

Comment: This new way looks very clean, but I don't understand why the block starting from line 7-22 gives `-1`. Doesn't `mockResponseData` have `status: 301` and here `axios.get.mockRejectedValue()` also have `status: 301`. So it should return `1` according to `getStatusCode()`?

Comment: I suppose a better way is to ask: Only at line 48 do you have `statusCode` as input argument. What is used as input `statusCode` for line 17 and 32?

Comment: I've tried to create a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224529/room-for-teneff-and-sandra-schlichting), but obviously it's not sending notifications

Comment: @SandraSchlichting on line 17 and 32 we're using the default value from `getStatusCode.js:7`, which is `0` to compare it to the `statusCode` returned from `axios.get`